# Zsh alias for changing git credential-osxkeychain

Tags: c, git, zsh, git-credential-manager

I regularly need to replace my default git osxkeychain credentials, using the command-line. The way I do it manually is as follows:

`git credential-osxkeychain erase` `<Enter>`
`host=github.com` `<Enter>`
`protocol=https` `<Enter>`
`password=foo` `<Enter>`
`username=bar` `<Enter>`
`<Enter><Enter>`

And then that process again, except with `git credential-osxkeychain store` and the new credentials. I'd like to automate it, something like

```
alias git_newcred='git credential-osxkeychain erase; host=github.com; protocol=https;git credential-osxkeychain erase; host=github.com; protocol=https;'
```

Where the `;` newlines are in place of the enter key. However, as it is this fails silently.

The beginning of the `read_credential` method in the source [looks like this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain.c#L117):

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
    char *v;

    if (!strcmp(buf, "\n"))
        break;
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
```

How do I alias multi-line entry, which is part of a single command? Or is there a better way to do this?

(Using zsh, but I don't think there's anything zsh-specific going on.)

Comment: If you are using `zsh`, the `bash` tag isn't appropriate.

Comment: I figured since it isn't zsh-specific, and zsh is a subset of bash, isn't `bash` the better tag (maybe instead of `zsh`)? The way that Python3 questions are just tagged `python` unless they involve some specific quirk of 3

Comment: `zsh` is most certainly *not* a subset of `bash`; it's an entirely different shell. They share many features in common, and even a good amount of syntax, but there is `bash` code that works differently or not at all if you attempt to execute it with `zsh`, and there is *tons* of `zsh` code that `bash` cannot execute. It would be more accurate (though still wrong) to call `zsh` a superset of `bash`.

Comment: OK, point taken. I'll untag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a function, not an alias. After you run `git`, the rest of the data is input to that command, not additional commands to be run by the shell. You can do that with a here document

```
git_newcred () {
    git credential-osxkeychain erase <<EOF
host=github.com
protocol=https
password=foo
username=bar
EOF
}
```

or with a pipe.

```
git_newcred () {
    # POSIX-compatible version
    # printf '%s\n' ... | git credential-osxkeychain
    print -l "host=github.com" "protocol=https" "password=foo" "username=bar" | git credential-osxkeychain
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. Is there any way I could do it where it would chain `erase` && `store` new credentials, and take username and password as $1 and $2 arguments? Also, should this be in my .zshrc or a separate file (or does it not matter)?

Comment: I would put it in `.zshrc`. You can replace `bar` with `$1` and `foo` with `$2`. As for chaining, the body of the function can consist of an arbitrary sequence of commands; just run `git credential-osxkeychain` on the line following `EOF`.